# How to send the value of multiple checkboxes whose value has changed in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I have a requirement in which on page load there will be multiple checkboxes. Some that are already checked whereas others which are unchecked. There is one save button. On click of that save button , I need to send only those checkbox values which are changed.

For example if checkbox 1 is false on page load , I checked it , then I need to send its value to backend but if I click it again and uncheck it, then I don't want to send its value

how can I achieve this?

Comment: This would be a simple matter of first finding all the checkboxes, looping over them and saving their current value/state in an array. Then, on the click of the button, do that again, but this time compare the current values against what you saved before. What have you tried?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry if i misunderstood your question. This code just separates the checkboxes into two arrays based on there checked state. If you check a box then click save it will move it from the checkboxes array into the checked array.

```
let cb1  = document.getElementById("cb1_");
let cb2  = document.getElementById("cb2_");
let cb3  = document.getElementById("cb3_");

let save = document.getElementById("save"); // save button

let checkboxes = []; // stores all checkboxes that are false
let checked_   = []; // stores all checkboxes that are true

checkboxes.push(cb1);
checkboxes.push(cb2);
checkboxes.push(cb3);

window.onload = function(){
    for(let i in checkboxes){
        if(checkboxes[i].checked == true){
            checked_.push(checkboxes[i]); // push to checked_ array
            let index = checkboxes.indexOf(checkboxes[i]); // get index
            checkboxes.splice(index,1); // remove from checkboxes
        }
        if(checkboxes[i].checked == false){
            // do something if false
        }
    }
};

save.addEventListener("click",function(){ 
    for(let i in checkboxes){
        if(checkboxes[i].checked == true){
            checked_.push(checkboxes[i]);
            let index = checkboxes.indexOf(checkboxes[i]);
            checkboxes.splice(index,1);
        }
        if(checkboxes[i].checked == false){
            // do something if false
        }
    }
});
```